# Setting Windows Permissions with Python

Tags: python, windows, permissions

I want to give a user only read access to a folder (a geodatabase) using Python. When I set the permissions manually through file explorer they work correctly. When using win32security and ntsecuritycon to set the permissions through Python I am able to give a user (myself) full control. However, when trying to give only read access to another user they are either not able to view the folder's contents, or are unable to even open the folder.

In both cases, whether the read permissions are set manually or with Python, I see the same permissions checked off in the "Permissions Entry for Folder_Name" window (navigated to by: right folder -> Properties -> Advanced -> Select user from list -> Edit). There is one difference between these two methods that I noticed; under the "folder_name" properties window there is a section that is titled Permissions for "User/Group_name". In this section there is a list of permissions with an associated allow and deny column; this is where the difference is. If the permissions are done manually then there will be a check for the "Read" row in the "Allow" column. If the permissions set with Python there will instead be a check for the "Special permissions" in the "Allow" column. I know don't if this is the issue, but I can't find any other difference between the two methods.

Here is the code I am using
`

def set_permissions(filefolderlist, readlist, authlist):

```
import sys
import win32security
import ntsecuritycon as con

for filefolderpath in filefolderlist:

    sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(
        filefolderpath, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION
    )

    dacl = win32security.ACL()
    
    sysadmins, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName("", "SYSTEM")
    admins, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName("", "Administrators")
    user, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName("", read_user)
    dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION, con.FILE_ALL_ACCESS, sysadmins)
    dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION, con.FILE_ALL_ACCESS, admins)
    dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION, con.GENERIC_READ, user)
    
    for auth_user in authlist:
        user, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName("", auth_user)
        dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION, con.FILE_ALL_ACCESS, user)

            sd.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(1, dacl, 0)
    win32security.SetFileSecurity(
        filefolderpath, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sd
    )
```

set_permissions(folder_list,read_user,user_list)`

Comment: Could it be GENERIC_READ mapping to something suboptimal? Inspect with `icacls` or https://helgeklein.com/setacl/

Comment: What would be something suboptimal? As far as I can tell (using icacls) it is mapping to R, which equals Read.

Comment: You have a working and a non-working ACL, dump both with a better tool and compare.